# texture paint or material

Tags: materials, game-engine, texture-painting

I have several objects forming one main object that each has one solid color ( I dont use texture for this stage). Suppose there is a building which includes several objects such as door lamp, window flowers...

There are two ways to color objects: using texture painting or using materials. My question is that should I use texture paint for coloring each object or should I use material panel ( creating one material for each object).

My final goal is to import 3D models into a game engine.

Thanks.

Comment: Some game engines don't support multiple materials in one object, so a texture might be needed anyway in some situations. You can also bake different materials into a texture and use that texture instead.

Comment: Is this a question regarding the Blender Game Engine? The tag [game engine] refers to the Blender Game Engine)